# Why did Steve Jobs say that Darwin is a kernel?

Tags: history, apple-macintosh, operating-system, terminology

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko4V3G4NqII), Steve Jobs introduces Mac OS X (in the year 2000), this is a snapshot from the video:

[image]

He says that Darwin is the kernel for Mac OS X.

Now the following is a diagram of the Mac OS X architecture (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_macOS)):

[image]

The diagram shows that the kernel for Mac OS X is XNU (not Darwin), and that Darwin is XNU plus system utilities.

Does the term "kernel" have many definitions?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is on-topic here.

Comment: This is not retrocomputing, but current computing.

Comment: Well it's formulated from a historic perspective, but I agree it's as well current. More so, it's about a question that can and will only attract *opinion* based answer (starting with the opinion what a kernel is or not). Therefore I'd vote off-topic.

Comment: Without getting too macabre, I'm pretty sure that Steve Jobs is not a current person in computing.

Comment: For current and past computing information, see SuperUser for starters.  https://superuser.com/a/329479/38062

Comment: I don't think it's fair to characterize his statement as meaning "Darwin is defined as a kernel".  It should be interpreted to mean "The OS kernel functionality is being provided by Darwin".  This does not mean that Darwin is all and only a kernel, just that Darwin has a kernel, and that's the one being used by Mac OS X.  As far as the upper layers in that diagram are concerned, the kernel is the most important thing Darwin provides.  During this kind of presentation there is little reason to bring up the fact that Darwin also includes system utilities.

Comment: Even if not a question for retrocomputing, it still is interesting, since the main question seems to be "What is a kernel?"

Answer (score 13):

The answer is simple, Jobs was simplifying for the media.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the term "kernel" have many definitions?

I guess that's the core (SCNR) issue here. Kernel is a quite vague definition. It's even visible in aboves picture as Mach itself is defined as a kernel, and everything above (like file systems) services that are added later. Then again, above graphics tie the Mach kernel with services (from the BSD project/kernel) and call the result ('xnu') again a kernel.

So when more utilities get added and bundled as 'Darwin' it is an arbitary coice to call it OS or kernel. In fact, the term 'core OS' coined here (whatever that should mean) sounds much like an attempt to avoid writing again'kernel'.

**Bottom line: What 'Kernel' means is an arbitrary decision for a vague concept.**

It is one of these *'I know it when I see it'* kind of words, concept words, that are great for a generalized abstract discussion, but do not work for an in detail description.

So for a concrete product, it's whatever parts the manufacturer calls so. And Jobs as CEO does hold some stake here, doesn't he?

(And [as John Dallman already mentioned](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9339/6659) a term for simplification and marketing, bendable as needed, to sell the product with some techno babel aura)

Comment: In the context of a modern multitasking operating system, the concept is pretty well defined. The kernel is the bit that provides the basic services that have to run with a higher level of privilege than normal. The kernel in mac OS is not Darwin, it is xnu. There is no ambiguity about it: Steve Jobs was using the term incorrectly.

Comment: @JeremyP Except, there is no consistent definition of what _basic services_ are. So anything based on a vague definition is by all logic in itself *not* 'prety well defined' but arbitrary.

Comment: Well no there isn't, but they are precisely defined as far as the XNU kernel is concerned (and also any other individual kernel, although they may not be the same set of basic services). In practical terms, the border between the kernel and user land is the point at which the CPU switches into privileged mode. Darwin is quite definitely not a kernel. XNU is a kernel. Linux is a kernel.

Comment: An incorrect answer is still an answer; please don't flag this as NAA.

Comment: @JeremyP _"border between the kernel and user land is the point at which the CPU switches into privileged mode"_ - so this means on systems/CPUs that do not have a privileged mode there can't be a kernel? That definition is flawed as well, isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn The first sentence of my first comment contextualises the point.

Comment: @JeremyP That's just a statement, not any validation or proof - after all, it again operates with a vague concept, here the term _'modern'_. Try defining it, and I'm pretty sure it becomes either cyclic or arbitrary again. I mean, beside the point, that this first line leaves non multi tasking kernels in a limbo, does it? **Kernel** is one of these terms that are great for generalized discussion, but do not work as definition. Like Car or Bread. When it comes to a concrete object it gets applied on arbitrary based.

Comment: @Raffzahn So what about non multitasking operating systems? We are talking about the macOS kernel. There's nothing vague about the definition of what constitutes the macOS kernel. There's nothing ambiguous about it. In fact, the same applies to almost any given operating system. The people who work with it know exactly what is in the kernel (or kernal in the case of one or two retro machines). If you say "macOS kernel" there is none of this ambiguity that you are pretending exists.

Comment: @JeremyP Jumping targets again? I assume because you try to avoide at all cost to agree, right? Well, if we **only** MacOS, then there is **only** one source to define this, and that's not me or you, but Apple - in this case the guy in charge of Apple. Not some people or other magical thinking. That's the way it works if a term is ambiguous: the boss rule :))

Comment: @Raffzahn No. Because you are wrong. Anybody who knows about OS's can easily identify the kernel in a modern operating system. If the definition were vague, it wouldn't be possible to do that. OK there may be some tricky ones in niche areas - especially embedded - but we weren't asked about those.

Comment: By the way, if you are trying to get me to reverse my downvote, it won't work, because I'm not one of the down voters.

Comment: Although I have to say, I'm not sure it's good etiquette to both vote for a question to be closed and provide an answer...